# Salvar arquivo no Banco de dados com PHP

Tags: php, html5, banco-de-dados, file-upload

Tenho uma aplicação web, onde esta tudo rodando certinho com exeção do upload de arquivos.

o PHP responsável por armazenar os dados no banco de dados e salvar o arquivo na pasta é esse

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("connect.php");

    $fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_email);
    $file = $_FILE['file']['name'];


            $result_file = "INSERT INTO work (fname, lname,email, file) VALUES (:fname, :lname,:email, :file)";
            $insert_msg = $con->prepare($result_file);
            $insert_msg -> bindParam(':fname',$fname);
            $insert_msg -> bindParam(':lname',$lname);
            $insert_msg -> bindParam(':email',$email);
            $insert_msg -> bindParam(':file',$file);


            if($insert_msg->execut()){
                $last_id = $con->lasInsertId();
                $folder = 'files/' .$last_id '/';

                mkdir($folder,0755);

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']$folder.$file);

                $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:gren;'> File sent successfully</p>";
            header("Location: index.php");
            }else{
                    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Failed to send file</p>";
                    header("Location: index.php")
            }
```

Mas ele não esta salvando nenhuma informação nem salvando o arquivo.

Comment: Em `if($insert_msg->execut())`, não deveria ser `if($insert_msg->execute())` ? Não está aparecendo nenhuma exceção?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ter alguns problemas no código apresentado e isso deve estar gerando erros em seu php.

Esta linha parece esta faltando uma `,` *(virgula)*

```
/// move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']$folder.$file );
///                                                ^
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $folder.$file );
    ///                                            ^
```

Não sei se o php vai reclamar mas vale apena colocar tudo em caps:

```
/// FILTER_SANITIZE_email
    ///             ^
    FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
    ///             ^
```

A variável `$_FILES` esta sem o `S`:

```
/// $file = $_FILE['file']['name'];
    ///           ^
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    ///           ^
```

Essas eu não tenho certeza, mas me parecem faltando letras:

```
/// $insert_msg->execut()
    ///                ^
    $insert_msg->execute()
    ///                ^

/// $con->lasInsertId();
    ///      ^
    $con->lastInsertId();
    ///      ^
```

Esse esta faltando um `.` para concatenar:

```
 /// $folder = 'files/' .$last_id '/';
     ///                         ^
     $folder = 'files/' .$last_id. '/';
     ///                         ^
```

E no ultimo `header` aqui falta um `;` no final da linha

```
/// header("Location: index.php")
    ///                          ^
    header("Location: index.php");
    ///                          ^
```

Referencia: [`move_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), [`$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), [`FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php#constant.filter-sanitize-email)